# How to create Index with custom analyzers from json file in Azure Search .NET SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I had read that the Azure Search .NET SDK uses NewtonSoft.Json to convert it's models to/from json in it's underlying REST API calls so I've been doing the same in my own app.

I have a simple app which creates a new Index using the .NET SDK. To do this, I was defining my Index in a json file, using the format outlined here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-index and then I was converting this to a Microsoft.Azure.Search.Models.Index object using Newtonsoft.

```
var index = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Microsoft.Azure.Search.Models.Index>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("config.json");
```

This was working fine before I configured custom Analyzers, but now that I have custom Analyzers in my config, the Analyzers, Tokenizers, and TokenFilters are not being resolved into the correct types. ie. my custom Analyzer is being deserialized as a Microsoft.Azure.Search.Models.Analyzer, instead of Microsoft.Azure.Search.Models.CustomAnalyzer, same goes for the Tokenizers and TokenFilters, they are being deserialized into the base types.

Is there an easy way I can create an Index like this in the .NET SDK from a json file?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not an officially supported scenario. While it works for simple index definitions, we're working to understand what we need to do to be able to support all cases.

Please post your feature request on our User Voice page to help us prioritize: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search

In the meantime, you might be able to get it working yourself by adapting the `JsonSerializerSettings` initialization code at the bottom of [this file](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/AutoRest/src/Search/Microsoft.Azure.Search/GeneratedSearchService/SearchServiceClient.cs).

Comment: I did manage to find a workaround to generate JSON that would be supported. I fetched my existing index (created with the REST API) using the .NET SDK, and then converted it to JSON using Newtonsoft with the TypeNameHandling.All JsonSerializer setting.  This generated a JSON file with annotated type information in the "$type" property.  I replaced my previous JSON file with this one and now I'm able to generate my index from this json file with the .NET SDK and all the correct types get applied. Thanks for your answer.